# Socket.io Redis Adapter Implementation/Usage Pattern

Tags: redis, adapter, publish-subscribe, socket.io-1.0

I've been looking for actual documentation for implementing a Socket.io Adapter with Redis and how to use. Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499306/how-to-set-redisstore-node-express-socket-io-heroku) bring this issue up but nowhere is there any.

- Why do I get `Error: ### trailing bytes` when all it says to do is return `return_buffers: true` in the document. I do that like: `publish = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost', {return_buffers: true});` Yet I still get it
- How do you use the adapter? Do I call it from Redis, or do I trigger the pubClient that I pass in?
- Is there a pattern for triggering the pub/sub? Ex. User removed from redis DB, how do I get that to the client side?
- Is there a specific format to publish objects as? I've deduced that it's supposed to be an array and arr[0] is an object. but not sure how to send it to different namespaces, or am I supposed to attach additional objects for additional data?

Any direction would be appreciated as the Socket.io documentation does not cover adapters